# Как рассмотреть все пары в массиве

Tags: python, массивы

Есть Массив от некоторого числа,введённого с клавиатуры до единицы(в обратном порядке) нужно рассчитать НОД(наибольший общий делитель) всех пар  в массиве.Как это сделать

Comment: `functools.reduce(math.gcd, array)`.

Comment: gcd встроен в какую то библиотеку?

Comment: Перед точками названия встроенных библиотек.

Comment: а с помощью 2 циклов как то можно?

Comment: как потом вывести наименьший результат из всех и как хранятся элементы после применения reduce -функции